# Nodejs bigint install

Tags: node.js, bigint

I am trying to install bigint:

https://github.com/substack/node-bigint

but I am not able due to the following errors:

[image]

The npm-debug.log file contains:

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
verbose cli   'install',
verbose cli   'bigint' ]
info using npm@1.1.21
info using node@v0.6.17
verbose C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe node symlink
verbose config file C:\Users\rkara\.npmrc
verbose config file C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc
verbose config file C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\package.json
verbose loadDefaults application-name@0.0.1
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\accounting\package.json
verbose loadDefaults accounting@0.3.2
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\azure\package.json
verbose loadDefaults azure@0.5.3
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\cron\package.json
verbose loadDefaults cron@0.3.2
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\ejs\package.json
verbose loadDefaults ejs@0.7.1
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\express\package.json
verbose loadDefaults express@2.5.8
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\http-get\package.json
verbose loadDefaults http-get@0.3.12
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\jade\package.json
verbose loadDefaults jade@0.25.0
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\node-uuid\package.json
verbose loadDefaults node-uuid@1.3.3
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\sprintf\package.json
verbose loadDefaults sprintf@0.1.1
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\underscore\package.json
verbose loadDefaults underscore@1.3.3
verbose from cache C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\package.json
verbose readDependencies: using package.json deps
verbose cache add [ 'bigint', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'bigint', [ 'bigint', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'bigint', path: 'bigint', href: 'bigint' }
verbose addNamed [ 'bigint', '' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'bigint', '', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging bigint
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './bigint' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/bigint
verbose etag "5IO0KO6KLRQHDBIRV0A68ADZ0"
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bigint
http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bigint
silly get cb [ 304,
silly get cb   { server: 'CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B)',
silly get cb     etag: '"5IO0KO6KLRQHDBIRV0A68ADZ0"',
silly get cb     date: 'Mon, 25 Jun 2012 06:21:46 GMT',
silly get cb     'content-length': '0' } ]
verbose etag bigint from cache
silly name, range, hasData 2 [ 'bigint', '', true ]
silly versions [ 'bigint',
silly versions   [ '0.0.1',
silly versions     '0.0.2',
silly versions     '0.0.5',
silly versions     '0.0.6',
silly versions     '0.0.7',
silly versions     '0.0.8',
silly versions     '0.0.9',
silly versions     '0.0.10',
silly versions     '0.0.11',
silly versions     '0.0.12',
silly versions     '0.1.0',
silly versions     '0.2.0',
silly versions     '0.2.1',
silly versions     '0.2.2',
silly versions     '0.3.0',
silly versions     '0.3.1',
silly versions     '0.3.2',
silly versions     '0.3.3',
silly versions     '0.3.4',
silly versions     '0.3.5',
silly versions     '0.3.6',
silly versions     '0.3.7',
silly versions     '0.3.8',
silly versions     '0.3.9' ] ]
verbose bin dist [ '0.6-ares1.7.5-DEV-evundefined-openssl0.9.8r-v83.6.6.25-win32-ia32-6.1.7601',
verbose bin dist   { shasum: '0e32f5f685001a74b45d4fd9dd2e6fcbac335422',
verbose bin dist     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/bigint/-/bigint-0.3.9.tgz' } ]
verbose has wscript [ undefined,
verbose has wscript   { file: 'C:\\Users\\rkara\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\bigint\\0.3.9\\package\\package.json',
verbose has wscript     gypfile: false,
verbose has wscript     contributors: false,
verbose has wscript     serverjs: false,
verbose has wscript     wscript: true } ]
verbose caching C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bigint\0.3.9\package\package.json
verbose loadDefaults bigint@0.3.9
silly resolved [ { name: 'bigint',
silly resolved     version: '0.3.9',
silly resolved     description: 'Arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic using libgmp',
silly resolved     main: './index.js',
silly resolved     repository: 
silly resolved      { type: 'git',
silly resolved        url: 'git://github.com/substack/node-bigint.git' },
silly resolved     keywords: 
silly resolved      [ 'gmp',
silly resolved        'libgmp',
silly resolved        'big',
silly resolved        'bignum',
silly resolved        'bigint',
silly resolved        'integer',
silly resolved        'arithmetic',
silly resolved        'precision' ],
silly resolved     author: 
silly resolved      { name: 'James Halliday',
silly resolved        email: 'mail@substack.net',
silly resolved        url: 'http://substack.net' },
silly resolved     devDependencies: { tap: '~0.2.5', put: '~0.0.6' },
silly resolved     license: 'MIT/X11',
silly resolved     engine: { node: '>=0.2.0' },
silly resolved     scripts: { install: 'node-waf configure build', test: 'tap test/*.js' },
silly resolved     _id: 'bigint@0.3.9',
silly resolved     dependencies: {},
silly resolved     optionalDependencies: {},
silly resolved     engines: { node: '*' },
silly resolved     _engineSupported: true,
silly resolved     _npmVersion: '1.1.21',
silly resolved     _nodeVersion: 'v0.6.17',
silly resolved     _defaultsLoaded: true,
silly resolved     _from: 'bigint' } ]
info into C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1 bigint@0.3.9
info installOne bigint@0.3.9
verbose from cache C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bigint\0.3.9\package\package.json
info unbuild C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint
verbose unpack C:\Users\rkara\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bigint\0.3.9\package.tgz
silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
silly extracting entry .npmignore
silly modified mode [ '.npmignore', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry .travis.yml
silly modified mode [ '.travis.yml', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry bigint.cc
silly modified mode [ 'bigint.cc', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry examples/
silly modified mode [ 'examples/', 438, 493 ]
silly extracting entry examples/gen.js
silly modified mode [ 'examples/gen.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry examples/perfect.js
silly modified mode [ 'examples/perfect.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry examples/simple.js
silly modified mode [ 'examples/simple.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry index.js
silly modified mode [ 'index.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry package.json
silly modified mode [ 'package.json', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry README.markdown
silly modified mode [ 'README.markdown', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/
silly modified mode [ 'test/', 438, 493 ]
silly extracting entry test/arithmetic.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/arithmetic.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/bitwise.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/bitwise.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/bit_length.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/bit_length.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/buf.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/buf.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/cmp.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/cmp.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/create.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/create.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/gcd.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/gcd.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/invertm.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/invertm.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/mod.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/mod.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/pow.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/pow.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/primes.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/primes.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/rand.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/rand.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/seed.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/seed.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry test/shift.js
silly modified mode [ 'test/shift.js', 438, 420 ]
silly extracting entry wscript
silly modified mode [ 'wscript', 438, 420 ]
verbose has wscript [ undefined,
verbose has wscript   { file: 'C:\\node\\pazooza3\\webrole1\\node_modules\\bigint\\package.json',
verbose has wscript     gypfile: false,
verbose has wscript     serverjs: false,
verbose has wscript     contributors: false,
verbose has wscript     wscript: true } ]
verbose caching C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint\package.json
verbose loadDefaults bigint@0.3.9
info preinstall bigint@0.3.9
verbose from cache C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint\package.json
verbose readDependencies: using package.json deps
verbose from cache C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint\package.json
verbose readDependencies: using package.json deps
silly resolved []
verbose about to build C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint
info build C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint
verbose from cache C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint\package.json
verbose linkStuff [ false,
verbose linkStuff   false,
verbose linkStuff   false,
verbose linkStuff   'C:\\node\\pazooza3\\webrole1\\node_modules' ]
info linkStuff bigint@0.3.9
verbose linkBins bigint@0.3.9
verbose linkMans bigint@0.3.9
verbose rebuildBundles bigint@0.3.9
info install bigint@0.3.9
verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
silly exec cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"
silly spawning [ 'cmd',
silly spawning   [ '/c', 'node-waf configure build' ],
silly spawning   'C:\\node\\pazooza3\\webrole1\\node_modules\\bigint' ]
info bigint@0.3.9 Failed to exec install script
info unbuild C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint
verbose from cache C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1\node_modules\bigint\package.json
info preuninstall bigint@0.3.9
info uninstall bigint@0.3.9
verbose unbuild bigint@0.3.9 [ true,
verbose unbuild bigint@0.3.9   'C:\\node\\pazooza3\\webrole1\\node_modules',
verbose unbuild bigint@0.3.9   'C:\\node\\pazooza3\\webrole1\\node_modules' ]
info postuninstall bigint@0.3.9
ERR! bigint@0.3.9 install: `node-waf configure build`
ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
ERR! 
ERR! Failed at the bigint@0.3.9 install script.
ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bigint package,
ERR! not with npm itself.
ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
ERR!     node-waf configure build
ERR! You can get their info via:
ERR!     npm owner ls bigint
ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
ERR! 
ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bigint"
ERR! cwd C:\node\pazooza3\webrole1
ERR! node -v v0.6.17
ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
ERR! message bigint@0.3.9 install: `node-waf configure build`
ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
ERR! errno {}
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Has anybody successfully install bigint and if so did you experience and fix this problem?

Comment: I am having this problem in node version > 4. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is node-waf which is a wrapper for the build system waf. It is not available on windows at the moment. There is a Node release that should solve the problem available here: http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/01/23/node-v0-7-1/

Havn't tried it but it is an unstable version so don't get your hopes up to much. Run it under linux and the problem is gone.

Comment: cheers marcus, i've just started looking at bigdecimal which seems to install okay, just testing it now, if that doesn't suite I'll try your solution.